# Как называется последовательное выполнение методов?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Встречаю в коде вот такое последовательное выполнение методов, например в jQuery:

```
$(элемент).attr('id', 'abc').fadeIn('fast');
```

Как такая конструкция называется и как ее добиться? В книжке вычитал, что это называется каскады, но ищу в инете про каскады и ничего не нахожу.

Скажите, как это называется в JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да это называется "каскад" или "цепочка" но вообще говоря это все лишь:

1) `$(параметр)` - функция которая формирует объект и возвращает
2) `$(...).метод()` - метод возвращённого объекта
3) Каждый метод возвращает сам объект `$`
4) Когда вся "цепочка" завершена созданный объект удаляется сборщиком мусора JS

Почитайте JavaScript - The Definitive Guide (я раньше сам задавался подобным вопросом) и гуглите в сторону объектов конструкторов замыканий локальных переменных анонимных ф-ций и т.д.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то возвращает объект метод **.end()**.

Comment: @Deonis наверное, я если честно ещё до изучения использования/работы JQ не дошёл :)

Answer (score 8):

Это называется [`Method chaining`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), применяется не только в `javascript`, но и в других языках. Является основной концепцией [`Fluent interface`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).